# cannot compile gcc or g++ libc_nonshared.a not recognized

Tags: 12.04, compiling, gcc, g++

I cannot compile C/C++ files anymore since using  a new account (I think it was since then anyway) and I'm getting a strange error every time I try to compile:

```
~$ g++ hello.cpp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It happens with both `gcc` and `g++` and I cannot find any help on this anywhere. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

`hello.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have corrupted `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a` file, try reinstall libc development files:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6-dev
```